# Certificate error while planning and applying Hashicorp sentinel policies

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, hashicorp-sentinel

I am completely new to using Hashicorp sentinel. I have generated the mocks and tests on my local environment and when I run a "sentinel test" command, it return a pass:

```
PASS - restrict-virtual-disk-size-and-type.sentinel
  PASS - test\restrict-virtual-disk-size-and-type\fail.hcl
  PASS - test\restrict-virtual-disk-size-and-type\pass.hcl
1 tests completed in 34.4456ms
```

When I try to run this policy set on my tfe worksapce (plan and apply), it gives me this error:

```
Operation failed: failed fetching Terraform: failed downloading terraform: failed downloading "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.4.0/terraform_1.4.0_linux_amd64.zip": GET https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.4.0/terraform_1.4.0_linux_amd64.zip giving up after 1 attempt(s): Get "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.4.0/terraform_1.4.0_linux_amd64.zip": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I have no idea how to bypass this error. I have terraform 1.5.3 installed on my windows computer. I have no idea why it's trying to install a linux zip file. I'd appreciate any help on this please.